# Is it true that $|a_i| \leq |b_i|$ implies $ \|\Psi a \|_\infty \leq \|\Psi b \|_\infty$ for elementwise nonnegative $\Psi$s?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices, normed-spaces

Denote by $\Psi \in \mathcal{P}$ the property that $\Psi$ has non-negative entries and independent columns. Does the following property hold for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$(\forall i. |a_i| \leq |b_i|) \Rightarrow (\forall \Psi \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}: \Psi \in \mathcal{P}, m > n . \|\Psi a \|_\infty  \leq \|\Psi b \|_\infty)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! Hint: find $a,b,\Psi$ which satisfy the requirements and such that $b$ is in the kernel of $\Psi$ but $a$ is not.

Edit: if one disturbs the columns slightly one can achieve that the columns are independent. Eg take $$\Psi=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0.9\\ 0.9 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$$ and $a=(1,1)^T$ and $b=(1,-1)^T$.